# How possible is my dwarf's biology?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, fantasy-races

One of the closest relatives of humans is unsurprisingly the dwarf, with a large disproportionate head and relatively short limbs. The dwarf weighs on average almost 150 pounds, with males being slightly larger than females at 165 pounds. Which is very surprising considering most dwarfs are in the range of 4ft and 5 inches tall. This is because dwarfs are very compact creatures with large muscles and fat, this makes dwarfs incredibly strong for their size.

Dwarfs are adapted for the cold and for cave living, which has led towards both sexes being capable of growing beards in equal length and thickness, at first glance it's very difficult to tell the two apart.
A dwarf’s beard is incredibly unusual in its morphology, each individual hair can move independently and sense the area around it like the tendrils of a star-nosed mole. Because of the advanced nature of the beard there are millions of complex tiny nerves in each strand of the beard which act like an individual, when the beard is pulled, cut, or twisted it causes considerable pain to the dwarf.

Many dwarf rulers prove their toughness by completely shaving off their beards, in some cases the beard may take decades to grow back and may not even grow back at all. But even with the drawbacks this ability gives dwarfs an advantage over other species in caves. As the dwarf can live and work in complete darkness with no problems because of the hairs sensory capabilities.

Dwarfish spit can harden once it leaves the mouth, the spit itself is a wonder of nature and can be as hard as concrete. Many structures are completely made out of their own spit, this ability is also quite useful for sealing cracks in crumbling cave walls. Dwarfs are capable of interbreeding with humans, but much like a mule the offspring will be infertile.

Comment: "_Many structures are completely made out of their own spit_" uh huh, some kind of secreted resin. "_Dwarfs are capable of interbreeding with humans_" do they do this by implanting eggs in human torsos, by any chance?

Comment: There's no science-based workout imho. Medusa dwarfs ? These "moving and sensing" beards.. the head hair is normal ? It feels really alien. There's no creature on our planet at least, that uses *hairs* as individual limbs with a sense on top. I wonder how a human may ever be able to breed with a species that has moving hairs. Unless you'd aspect the humans of your planet to have the same property.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Haha, clever joke but no.

Comment: @Goodies The hair on their head on their head is normal. I was thinking instead of it being completely made of hair, there's instead thin lines of tiny muscles in each strand which is they can move and sense their surroundings. Much like a star nosed mole, though I'm not sure how biologically possible this is. I could potentially drop the moving independent beard hairs if it doesn't make much sense. I was really trying to have the beards be used to sense their surroundings, and if they moved it would make it more easier.

Comment: @Goodies I was considering that humans and dwarfs would probably be too distant to breed with each other, unless I got rid of the moving beards or like you mentioned the humans on that planet have a similar property.

Comment: @WilburWummins your design will be a challenge. How would these beards look like beards ? How would they have 16-30 muscle-supported, thick beard hairs instead of >800 ? With normal beard hairs, there's too little to support or attach, even with "tiny muscles".. Hairs are thin, they consist of horn and pigment, they are not "living tissue" tentacles. This is no reason to avoid it, you can find solutions for it, but you can't state they "interbreed" with humans, unless the humans share a similar property. It is a major design change.. and creatures which differ too much simply don't breed.

Comment: @Goodies Thank you very much for your insight. I was thinking that the hairs are attached to thin strands of muscles, so the hair itself doesn't move but the skin and muscle its attached to does. So a shaved dwarf's face would look really saggy and almost kinda look like its face was covered in little strands of skin. I probably should've mentioned this, but humans do share a common ancestor with dwarves about 4 million years ago.

Comment: The concept sounds really alien to be a dwarf other than the mere fact they have beards, TBH. Traditional fantasy genres dwarves are also too proud to cut off their beards, and these are sensitive beards at that? That implies nerve endings, that implies it would hurt a lot when cut.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief I was trying to make my dwarfs more original in concept, as I feel like there's a lot of overdone trops when it comes to that species. But I do understand if you feel like it deviates a lot from the original concept. Also the reason why a dwarf may cut his beard is to prove his toughness, for instance most dwarf's would scream in pain if their beard got cut. But if he doesn't scream everyone around him is gonna think he's incredibly tough. But this would be very uncommon, and probably be done by dwarfs who aren't the brightest.

Answer (score 2):

The solidifying saliva is something already seen on Earth, for example in the [Edible-nest swiflet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible-nest_swiftlet)

> The edible-nest swiftlet (Aerodramus fuciphagus), also known as the white-nest swiftlet, is a small bird of the swift family which is found in South-East Asia. Its opaque and whitish nest is made exclusively of solidified saliva and is the main ingredient of bird's nest soup, a delicacy of Chinese cuisine.

Considering that a male takes about 35 days to build a nest, it seems far fetched that the dwarf can use saliva to seal cracks in the rocks, unless they drool copiously.

About the beard, it's also plausible that it becomes highly sensitive, like the animal you give as a reference. However, since it is used as sensory organ (which makes sense in the darkness of a cave) it seems a poor choice to cut it off. It sounds like a top piano player breaking their fingers to prove how good they are.